# Change google default direction map color

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to change the color of default google map. Is there any parameter i can send in url?

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=destination_lat,destination_lon

I don't want to create map in my app and customize it . I just want to add some parameter to change the color of default google map to above url.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer is; You cannot apply style on Google Maps like this. 
Although it is possible to style it when calling static maps in your page see
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps